# how to highlight a draggable node in jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

i am using jstree, in this i am using drag and drop plugin, i am returning a message when node is not movable in that case i need to highlight which node is dragged so can anyone please help me for this. here is my code ...

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/UpdateManagerID",
            data: { NodeID: data.node.id, ParentID: data.parent, OldParentID: data.old_parent },

            success: function (response) {

                if (response.Status == true) {
                    alert(response.Message);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error Code: " + response.Code + "\n" + response.Message);
                    $.jstree.reference($("#jstree")).refresh(-1);

                    $("#jstree").jstree("select_node", "#1");

                }
            }
        });
```

as you can see when it returns error code, than i want to highlight the node.

Comment: why can't you store reference to node before sending ajax?

Comment: because when error comes i need to prevent dragged node, but my problem is i need to highlight that node also.

Comment: Put this ajax call(should be sync) in drag_start callback and return false; on failure so that drag move prevented. Unless you change selected node it will be highlighted automatically, since you are setting to Root, you may keep reference before calling ajax and set that node as selected too.